# como carregar varias fotos para o aplicativo Ionic

Tags: ionic, native, câmera

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no qual serão salvas algumas fotos, eu consigo usar a camêra e tudo funciona corretamente, minha duvida é: Como adicionar mais de uma foto ?

Segue meu código:

No provider da camera:

```
private _getPicture(source: number, callback): void {
    if(this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() =>{
        try {
          //definidno as opções e configurações da foto
          let options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 70,
            //DATA_URL é a imagem convertida em base64, vai devolver em base64 pra gente
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            //definindo da onde vai vir, aqui se escolhe se irá vir da câmera, galeria, etc.
            sourceType: source,
            //se permite a pessoa editar a foto depois de tirar
            allowEdit: true,
            //como a imgem será salva
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
             //escolher se a foto vai ser salva na galeria do celular
             saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
             //defenir a orientação correta
             correctOrientation: true             
          }

            this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imgData)=>{
                //ajustando a imagem, e no final ${}=> vai o que será o resultado da captura
                  let base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imgData}`
                  callback(base64Image);
            }, err =>{
                  console.log('Problema ao capturar a foto', err)
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('problema ao tirar a foto', error)
        }

      })
    }else {
      alert('Disponibilidade disponível somente no device');
    }
}

//criando método para pegar a foto da galeria
public getPictureFromGalery(callback): void{
this._getPicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, photo =>{ 
  //pegando a foto escolhida
  callback(photo)
});
}

//criando um método para tirar a foto
public takePicture(callback): void {
this._getPicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, photo =>{
  //pegando a foto tirada
  callback(photo)
});
}
```

No ts da tela em que escolho a foto:

```
getPictureOptions(): void {
  //actionSheet serve para aparecer as opções, se a foto será escolhida na galeria ou tirada na hora.
  let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'Adicionar foto',
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Tirar foto', handler: () => {
        //escolhendo a opção de tirar foto no cameraprovider que foi criado, e assumindo o valor da photo para o projeto.foto
        this.cameraSrvc.takePicture(photo =>{
          this.projeto.foto = photo;
        })

      }, 
      icon: this.platform.is('ios') ? null : 'camera' },
//------------------------ Opção pegar da galeria ------------
      { text: 'Pegar galeria', handler: () =>{
        this.cameraSrvc.getPictureFromGalery(photo =>{
          this.projeto.foto = photo;
        })

      }, icon: this.platform.is('ios') ? null : 'images'},
      //o role 'destructive' deixa o botao vermelho
      {text: 'Cancelar', role: 'destructive', 
      icon: this.platform.is('ios') ? null : 'close'
    ,handler: () => {
        //cancela a ação
      }, }
    ]
  });
  actionSheet.present();

}
```

Aonde a foto será exibida:

```
 <ion-row>
                        <ion-item text-center>
                            <button ion-button clear (click)="getPictureOptions()"><ion-icon name="camera" item-left></ion-icon> Selecionar Foto</button>
                          </ion-item>
                    </ion-row>
                    </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>

                    <ion-item *ngIf="projeto.foto">
                        <img [src]="projeto.foto">
                      </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o plugin nativo você não consegue fazer isso. Apenas bater uma foto de cada vez.

Mas há uma solução:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-multi-camera

Comment: Gesiel minha dúvida é de como adicionar uma por uma mesmo, saberia ? eu criei 2 campos de foto, porém quando tiro uma foto a mesma é adicionada nos dois campos

Comment: É que vc está colocando as fotos sempre na mesma variável "this.projeto.foto = photo;". Se vc quer multiplas fotos, vc tem que ter um array de fotos. Então o "this.projeto.foto" tem que ser um array, e não uma string. Quando vc receber a nova foto, vc faz um "this.projeto.foto.push(photo)". E no HTML vc vai ter que fazer um FOR para exibir todas as imagens do array. Se quiser um exemplo, tem esse: https://www.9lessons.info/2017/04/ionic2-angular2-camera-native-multiple.html

Comment: esse this.projeto.foto vem do banco, onde foto é um capo de lá, como transformo esse campo em um array ?

Comment: Cara até consgui, mas deu um erro de carga útil muito grande 'Payload Too Large'

Comment: Problema resolvido, valeu Gesiel!